# Maven - Skip the goal execution by passing parameter

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm using this maven plugin:

```
<groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

I want to be able to pass in a parameter to skip the execution of the specified goal. (e.g. `mvm install -skipGemPlugin=true`)
How do I do that?

Comment: If you calling `mvn tomcat:run` than the gem-maven-plugin will not be executed cause you don't start a life cycle. Just the tomcat plugin is executed.

Comment: My `tomcat:run` calls the `install` goal which calls the gem-maven-plugin. Updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Can you show your pom file = How calls tomcat:run the install goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate profile to run tomcat and skips the goal execution:

```
<profile>
    <id>foo</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compassProcessSource</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call "bin" to your assembly.xml and in pom.xml put

```
<descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>bin</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

the plugin use a default assembly definition named "bin" and it annoys you!

SOLUTION: Remove bin and curses its creators